# Make one of the views in TouchableOpacity not trigger onPress event

Tags: react-native

So I have a TouchableOpacity Component with 3 views in a container inside of it.

I want to make one of them not trigger the onPress on TouchableOpacity. Is that possible?

```
<TouchableOpacity>
 <View>
       <View>Clickable</View>
       <View>Clickable</View>
       <View>NOT clickable</View>
 </View>
<TouchableOpacity/>
```

Comment: You can embed each view with TouchableOpacity where you required the onPress and can set the same callback method for onPress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<View>
   <TouchableOpacity>
       <View>Clickable</View>
       <View>Clickable</View>
   <TouchableOpacity/>
       <View>NOT clickable</View>
 </View>
```

Comment: Thats not what I mean, it still need to be "highlighted" when other views are touched, thats why I need everything in TouchableOpacity

Comment: May be you can put the none clickable View in its own TouchableOpacity so you treat its onPress differently.